# Tweaking Prime[n] to return 1 when n==0

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

I manually evaluate this cell to set Prime[0]

```
Unprotect[Prime]
Prime[0] = 1
Protect[Prime]
```

I manually evaluate this cell to reset Prime[0]

```
Unprotect[Prime]
Prime[0] =.
Protect[Prime]
```

In case I forget to do it, is there a way to automatically evaluate the second cell when I close the nb?

**Motivation**

I'm working with bags of primes and want to use $p_0$ as the bag for all prime greater than the square-root of some $n$.

Displayed as: $\left\{p_0^1,p_1^5,p_2^2,p_3^1,p_4^1\right\}$

With counts as: $\left\{1,5,2,1,1\right\}$

Comment: Have you seen [`NotebookEventActions[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookEventActions.html)?

Comment: You also could just define something like: `prime[x_Integer /; x >= 0] := If[x == 0, 1, Prime[x]]` as another approach.

Comment: @J.M.-- Looks interesting. I determined that if I exit mma, the change gets reset automatically.  It's only a problem when I open or create nbs from the current session.  Thanks.

Comment: I was hoping you'd answer your question yourself, since you figured out how to use it... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per J.M., I did this and it works.  I put it in the same cell as the setup.

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[],NotebookEventActions ->
Quiet[{Unprotect[Prime]; Prime[0] =.; Protect[Prime];}]}];
{Unprotect[Prime]; Prime[0] = 1; Protect[Prime]};
```

Edited to add the `Quiet` to the actions.

Comment: Nice work. :) ${}$